# How to empty trash on external disk on MacOS?

Tags: mac, spotlight, trash

I am using MacOS Ventura 13.1 and I want to do something really complicated and hard: Empty the trash on an external drive!

1. Normal method: Open Trash, click on empty:

   ```
   The operation can't be completed because the item XXX is in use
   ```
2. Open Trash, clicking on "Delete immediately":

   ```
   The operation can't be completed because some items had to be skipped. For each item ...
   ```
3. Trying the command line

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /Volume/MyDisk/.Trashes
   rm: /Volumes/MyDisk/.Trashes/: Operation not permitted
   ```
4. Trying to stop all these useless and superannoying spotlight processes and try any of the methods from above: No success

   ```
   sudo killall mds
   ```

Ok experts, how to just empty the Trash on an external disk? Buy a Linux Laptop to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your machine is in a state where one or more trashed files are *in use*... typically held open by some process - might well a "zombie" process which will never recover. Method #1 *will* work after the file handle has been returned by the process.

To remedy that, try to unmount the external drive. If this doesn't work either, unfortunately you will have to reboot.

Then mount the external drive again, open Trash, and click on empty.

---

By the way there is absolutely no need to kill `mds`... there is an option to exclude drives or subdirectories from spotlight indexing in the system preferences.

Comment: I did unmount/mount the drive which did not help. I will try to reboot, but rebooting whenever there is a small problem is very inefficient ...